# Can't determine version runtime when publishing web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Have a site that runs fine on localhost. But when i publish to my azure website i get the following error
[image]

The only things that i have changed from the base mvc templated is that I am using Entity Framwork for a database that is on Azure as well.  And Automapper for dependency injection operations. Currently set up using Repositories/ Services and Unit of Work model. I changed the webconfig so custom erros is set to OFF, which i did after this came up:
[image]

I googled around but i could really find anything related to this but I also don't really know where I need to be looking.

edit:

ASP.net v4.5.2
MVC 5
Visual studio pro 2015

adjusting project properties to 4.6 as well as changing the target framework in web.config to 4.6, I get this

[image]

Comment: What's the .net and mvc version?

Comment: asp.net 4.5.2 and mvc (5) template - visual studio pro 2015

Comment: Your site is configured to use .net 4.6 ?

Comment: In azure, like this http://s12.postimg.org/4h195atel/Captura.png

Comment: in azure it is set to .net 4.6. Same as the image you provided. I tried to adjust the project properties to build to 4.6 and change the target frameworks to 4.6 but no avail. Get a compilation error (see edit to question)

Comment: I can move to an asp.net 5 Preview template and work from there if need be. (Publishing works). Would prefer not but from what i have read that .net release seems stable